# How to put text on a CSS Triangle

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I must be missing a simple step. I have made a triangle in CSS and I'm trying to put text on top of the triangle. It works if I don't have the `width:0;` and `height:0;` but the triangle does not size right without it. The text is in there, but it wont show on the triangle. Can someone assist?

```
     .log{ /*bottom*/
        width:0; height:0;
        top:73.2%; left:36.4%;
        z-index:2;
        background-color:#E3DFD2;
        border-top:12vw solid black;
        border-right:9vw solid transparent ;
        border-left:9vw solid transparent;
        transform-origin: -10% -10%;
        transition:transform .2s .1s;
        color:#FFFFFF;
     }

     .log:hover{
       border-top:12vw solid white;
       border-right:9vw solid transparent ;
       border-left:9vw solid transparent;
       opacity:.5;
       color:#000000;
     }
```

Here is the HTML

```
  <a class="log" href="#"><p class="login">Member LogIn</p></a>
```

I want it to look something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try something like this :

```css
body{
  background: red;
}

.log{
  position: relative;
  border-bottom:100px solid transparent ;
  border-left:100px solid transparent;
  border-top: 180px solid black;
  border-right:100px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.log:hover{
  border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.log:hover .login{
  color: #000;
}

.login{
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  left: -50%;
  top: -90px;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px 0;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
```

```html
<a class="log" href="#">
  <span class="login">Member<br>LogIn</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out this

```css
.up {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 0 100px 173.2px 100px;
    border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
    float: left;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    display:block
}

.up span {
    text-align: center;
    left: -47px;
    top:25px;
    position: relative;
    width: 93px;
    height: 93px;
    margin: 0px;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<a class="up" href="#">
    <span>TEXT TEXT TEXT</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Here you go. You have the whole triangle as "a" tag? Or only the inner text? @I'm just a coder for fun